# NHibernate PropertyRef fluent mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way to make query over joins on different nullable foreign key?

Release notes: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.2.4/releasenotes.txt#L103

- A collection mapped with a `property-ref` will no more support being accessed
  when the referenced property is null. It will throw. Previously, the collection
  was not throwing but was always loaded empty.

`HasMany(m => m.SomeChildrenList).PropertyRef("Property");` => exception is thrown since Property can be null in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not using the correct syntax to describe your navigation property.

```
HasMany(m => m.SomeChildrenList).KeyColumn("Property");
```

Using `.PropertyRef("...")` throws an exception because there are no properties with this name in your entity class.